# How to have parent and child repos that are easy to use?

Tags: git

I want to start a project, with 3 git repos. The directory structure will look like this:

```
readme.md
src
  - core
  - test
```

I want to have a git repo of each part of the "whole project", like this:

```
core            <- seperate repo
test            <- seperate repo
src, readme.md  <- seperate (parent) repo
```

So "core" and "test" depend on each other and the "parent" repo with src and the readme.md (and a couple other stuff) is the "holder" repo, of the 2 child repos. In my workflow I will often and almost entirely change the "core" and "test" repos but hardly ever the "parent" repo.

How can I do this so it's easy to work with the 3 repos, but they're all still separate with their respective commits?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What advantages do you think this setup will provide over simple subdirectories? It's possible to do with [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [subtrees](https://gist.github.com/SKempin/b7857a6ff6bddb05717cc17a44091202), but I'm skeptical this is a good idea.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yeah, I want to implement uncle bob´s clean architecture ( if youre familiar with that ), where I seperate the test framework from the "core" part, so the test folder could also be called: testImplementation or something like this...

Comment: In that case I would suggest using a package registry (GitLab can be your private [package registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/) if you want). `core`, `test` are then packages and `readme.md`/`src` is your application.

Comment: And if I had to chose between submodules and subtrees, what would be the better options for my requirements?

Comment: What are your requirements? You haven't explained them. What are you trying to do that can't be done with a single project?

Comment: @JohnKugelman sorry that was a wrong word... I meant for my workflow, which I have described in my question :)

Comment: I personally hate submodules. They bring pain. If you can avoid them, do so. Just have the three repositories and manually clone each one. This brings its own pain, but it's a smaller pain. Or, just use a single monorepo: this is painless, and unless you have a *really strong* reason to split up the monorepo, why are you splitting up the monorepo?